# Rails - Rack Attack gem throttle with AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, throttling

I have tried to set up Rack Attack gem for throttling. However, I use aws elastic beanstalk and I found that because of the load balancers, users' ip address will be the same for all requests. Is there a way to work around it and get user's ip or any other way to set it up?
This is the code that I have right now for Rack Attack gem:

```
class Rack::Attack
    Rack::Attack.cache.store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new

    Rack::Attack.throttle('req/ip', :limit => 10, :period => 10.second) do |req|
        req.ip
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You're looking for "How to configure a Proxy Protocol Support"

> Proxy Protocol is an Internet protocol used to carry connection information from the source requesting the connection to the destination for which the connection was requested. Elastic Load Balancing uses Proxy Protocol version 1, which uses a human-readable header format.

[Configure Proxy Protocol Support for Your Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html)

### Contents

- [Proxy Protocol Header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html#proxy-protocol)
- [Prerequisites for Enabling Proxy Protocol](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html#proxy-protocol-prerequisites)
- [Enable Proxy Protocol Using the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html#enable-proxy-protocol-cli)
- [Disable Proxy Protocol Using the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html#proxy-protocol-disable-policy-cli)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for!